# Cocoa - Is there a way to check on whether not a cache exists for a NSURLConnection?

Tags: cocoa, caching, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I would like to be able to log monitor/log when a local machine cache is being used or when the data is being drawn from the remote source.

is there a NSURLConnection.cacheExists method?  Or better still one that shows the expiration date or other cache details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask [the shared NSURLCache object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/cachedResponseForRequest:) for [a cached response for a request](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/cachedResponseForRequest:).